# How does weighted_metric support the sample_weight in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I read the official doc for [creating custom metric](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#creating-custom-metrics). It says:

> Note that sample weighting is automatically supported for any such metric.

I wonder how sample weighting is supported for complicated metric. For example, a metric to compute **weighted** correlation between `y_true` and `y_pred` in Keras. Code below:

```
def customized_correlation(y_true, y_pred, sample_weights):
    x = y_true
    y = y_pred
    mx = K.mean(x)
    my = K.mean(y)
    xm, ym = x - mx, y - my
    r_num = K.sum(xm * ym * sample_weights)
    r_den = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(xm) * sample_weights) * K.sum(K.square(ym) * sample_weights))
    r = r_num / r_den
    return r
```

If we remove the `sample_weights` variable in code, how does Keras know where sample_weights should be inserted to calculate the weighted correlation?

Answer (score 0):

It does not, and it will not work. Using `sample_weights` simply means the resulting metric vector will be multiplied (element-wise) by weight vector at the very end

Comment: "Resulting metric vector at the very end"? I thought my calculation generates a value instead of a vector, and there is no vector generated except `xm` and `ym`. Does it mean `sample_weights` is not applied to my result at all? Further question: It seems custom metric function does not accept `sample_weights` as a parameter. how can I use `sample_weights` in my case?